# Liquibase using maven for generateChangeLog with multiple schema

Tags: liquibase

In my project we want to generate sql using liquibase for multiple schemas we are using. I have configured the maven plugin with single schema and it working fine but when I am trying to configure multiple schemas with executions it is not working. I tried it by creating by different profiles and specific goal to that profile and it works file but I want it to run in single goal with all schemas with different changelog specific to each schema.

below is the configuration I am using for single schema

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>${project.build.directory}/unpack/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <outputChangeLogFile>${project.build.directory}/liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml</outputChangeLogFile>
                    <changeLogFile>${project.build.directory}/liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffTypes>tables, views, columns, indexes, foreignkeys, primarykeys, uniqueconstraints, data</diffTypes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- ojdbc6.jar example -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- ojdbc7.jar example -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-change-log</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateChangeLog</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sync-sql-log</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>changelogSync</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sql-log</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>updateSQL</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: When you say 'not working' can you be more specific? Is there an error? If so, what is the error? Are the results different than you expected? If so, what results did you expect, and what were the actual results?

Comment: Steve I was getting issue related to the db credentials (user/password not correct) during execution of the goal even though all are correct and I was able to connect using sql command line. I resolve the issue by creating multiple execution and passing specific property file where I have mentioned details related to the schema specific details and it is working fine and generating all the files as expected.

Comment: <execution>
      <id>generate-change-log1</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
       <propertyFile>${project.build.directory}/unpack/first_liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
       <outputChangeLogFile>${project.build.directory}/changeLog_1.xml</outputChangeLogFile>
       <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
       <outputDefaultSchema>true</outputDefaultSchema>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
       <goal>generateChangeLog</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution> Same configuration used with other schema properties :)

Comment: You should note your resolution in an answer and accept your own answer rather than leaving it in a comment.